# AES standard C library implementation

Tags: hash, aes, block-cipher, rijndael

I'm working to implement AES (128/256 - either) on one of the [RISCV ISA](https://riscv.org/) processors & later improve performance by introducing a custom instruction in RISCV ISA.

I'm a crypto newbie and plan to use the 
[NIST test vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/AES_Core_All.pdf) to validate this C code.

I need to know the below things

1) Is there a link wherein i can find implementation of AES using standard C library ?

2) Do i have to use some hashing scheme along with AES ?  If yes, which one ?

3) Is it a good idea to validate my AES C code  with the NIST test vectors

4) Do you recommend using a encryption library instead ? If so where can i find it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but library recommendations and implementation recommendations are off-topic here (i.e. your question #1 and the second half of the fourth). They won't be answered because they could get outdated and be actively missleading at that point.

Comment: 1) I implemented AES in C (with some optimizations of my own) in http://mokkong-shen.privat.t-online.de 2) No. 3) Yes. cf. also my Python implementation of AES in http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7285224/1/ 4) No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Don't roll your own. (AKA: The first rule of cryptography.)**](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/915/110640)

[image]

## Do not create your own cipher, do not implement a cipher.

> Is there a link wherein i can find implementation of AES using standard C library ?

You can find a C implementation of AES in [The Design of Rijndael](http://jda.noekeon.org/#RijndaelBook), Section E, page 221. Test vectors are also provided in Section D. However, it is not recommended to use this implementation because it is vulnerable to 
cache timing attacks:

- [Cache-timing attacks on AES.](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#cachetiming): Dan J. Bernstein
- [Cache Attacks and Countermeasures](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/271.pdf): the Case of AES, Dag Arne Osvik, Adi Shamir and Eran Tromer
- [Faster and Timing-Attack Resistant AES-GCM](https://cryptojedi.org/papers/aesbs-20090616.pdf): Emilia Kasper and Peter Schwabe

> Do i have to use some hashing scheme along with AES ? If yes, which one ?

You need a hashing scheme only if you want to provide authenticity/integrity (see [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) schemes, for more reading about this see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac)).
Thus having a hashing scheme along is completely independent to having your AES implementation. You might however want to have a look at AES with [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) or [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode)  to provide authentication.

For hashing function, if you go **by the standards**, it is advised to use at least **SHA-256** or even better **SHA3-256** (as specified in [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) by the NIST).

> Is it a good idea to validate my AES C code with the NIST test vectors

It is more than a good idea. **It is required**. However, making your implementation work and produce the same results as the test vectors does not guarantees you that your implementation is correct (it does still provide you a strong confidence that your code might be correct). You have to check that every parts of your implementation matches the specifications of the algorithm.

> Do you recommend using a encryption library instead ? If so where can i find it ?

**Using a encryption library is highly recommended.** It will prevent you from suffering from cache timing attacks and other nasty things. It also guarantees that the code is *correctly* implemented. As for which library to use, at the time of the post (October 2016), you can have a look at [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/), [Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) or [NaCl](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/).